# Fetching 1 result for each ‘IN’ statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have big table with loads of records. I want to fetch a single record for each item in an `IN()` in the query

Example:

```
select dccid, marketid from market where marketid in ('1','2','3'...)
```

In the table `market` there are lots of records for each `marketid` but I just need 1 record for each market.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Is marketid an int or a string?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. When you say there are many records for each `where in` clause but you only want one date, do you mean you need to add another `where`clause or you want the most recent date?

Comment: I am using my sql

Comment: Marketid is Int only

Comment: "sql" does not answer the question. MySql and Sql Server are two different kinds of database that both use the SQL language, but with different dialects of the language that directly speak to this question.

Comment: Then you should ints, not string literals. It should be In(1, 2, 3)

Comment: You need to provide some clarity here. What is the input and what is the expected output? It sounds like you want to generate a delimited list??? Might be time for a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah but what should be the logic??

Comment: The in put is multiple int s like 5,12,52.and I need to fetch 1 result for each market_id and the resultset will fetch the dcid also.The table is having multiple records for each market id and dc ids are unique in the table.

Comment: As I already said....[mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by market_id order by market_id) as seqnum
      from market m
      where market_id in ( . . . )
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can change the `order by` to get a *particular* row -- the first, last, whatever.

That said, I don't understand why you would have duplicate `market_id`s in a table called `market`.  It seems like that should be the primary key.

Comment: For 1 market id there ll multiple dcids in the table,I need a single record having dcid for each market

Comment: @user12338558 That's what `row_number()` is for... but we still need to know what database you're using, as GA MySql releases have only supported this for the last year, and lots of real MySql installations haven't updated to a new enough version to support this yet.